# add a column to multiple text files with bash

Tags: for-loop, awk

I am trying to add a formatted column between columns of multiple text files. By using

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR]=$3;l=NR;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[l]" "$2}7' file file
```

I can convert a file that has a form

```
1 2 3 4
10 20 30 40 
100 200 300 400
```

to

```
1 1800 3 4
10 9900 30 40
100 90900 300 400
```

How can I do above operation to multiple .dat files?

Comment: Do it in a `for` loop in your shell.

Comment: I know but how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmp="/usr/tmp/tmp$$"
for file in *
do
    awk '...' "$file" "$file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

wrt your script, though:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR]=$3;l=NR;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[l]" "$2}7' file file
```

Never use the letter `l` (el) as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` (one). I'd actually write it as:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[++n]=$3;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[n]" "$2}7' file file
```

or if memory is a concern for a large file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR==1]=$3;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[0]" "$2}7' file file
```

Comment: I used the following:
tmp="../tmp$$"; for file in *.text; do awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR]=$3;l=NR;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[l]" "$2}7' "$file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$file"; done.
but it just delete the files.

Comment: yeah, it would. You forgot to specify the file twice on the arg list.